# The quickest way to find if object has a certain property and truth?

Tags: javascript

I want to do the simple yet need the fastest way of doing so in javascript:

I have this array :

```
   players: [{
       isInjured : false,
       name: ... 
       stamina : 50
   },{
       isInjured : true,
       name: ...,
       stamina : 20
   }
   ...
]
```

I have 2 things i want to do in the best, fastest way possible:

1)If i have in the array a true in the "inInjured" Property, to anyone.

2) i want to extract the 3 lowest stamina players, and extract the key of one of those.

I want to avoid, if possible, from doing 2 forEach for this, so what is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var players = [{
  isInjured: false,
  stamina: 50
}, {
  isInjured: false,
  stamina: 10
}, {
  isInjured: false,
  stamina: 15
}, {
  isInjured: false,
  stamina: 16
}, {
  isInjured: true,
  stamina: 20
}];



// Your second request you can do with lodash or underscore easily

var threePlayersWithMinStamina = _.take(_.sortBy(players, function(player) {
  return player.stamina;
}), 3);

console.log(threePlayersWithMinStamina) // you have the three players with the min stamina

//Your first request
// the var isOneInjured will be true if the condition will be true and stop the loop
var isOneInjured = players.some(function(player) {
  return player.isInjured;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array native [*some*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function like bellow

```
var isSomeoneInjurd = players.some(function(pl){
    return pl.isInjured;
});
```

The value of `isSomeoneInjurd` will be true if any of player has property `isInjured` as true. And it will break the loop as soon as it gets one true for that property.